# Vinculum number of 989?

Tags: number-theory, mental-arithmetic

To find vinculum number I was subtracting finding the complement of 989 and cosidering the number to be 0989 I raised the 0 to 1 so my answer was 1011 , but why was the answer given 1111 ? Do I also have to raise the 0 by 1 if the next number is above 5 ?

Comment: Some googling makes me think you mean *vinculum, but even so I don't understand the use of this technique. What computations are you trying to do, and why must you do them mentally instead of on paper or with a calculator?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee sorry its vinculum my fault . I am trying to learn mental math because we are not allowed calculators in exams .

Comment: Do your exams also not allow pencil and paper? :)

Comment: Do you mean [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_symbol#Origin)?

Comment: It seems to me that $0989=10\bar1\bar1=1\cdot10^3+0\cdot10^2+-1\cdot10+-1$, not $1\bar1\bar1\bar1$ or $1\bar1\bar1\bar1$ or any number with four digits that are $1$ or $\bar1$.

Comment: @SteveKass you answer gives 1089. Actually consider 1000-10-1

Comment: Blincer, I’m confused. My answer is 1000-10-1, which is what you say I should consider.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee they allow pen and paper , but the rough space is limited , and also I want to understand this and to learn this technique I dont see anything wrong with it .

Answer (score 0):

1**011** is the right answer.
In fact, when you take the complement of the numbers directly preceding a number greater than 5 you have to add to 9 instead of 10.

I recommend the following slide show:
https://slideshare.net/culturalcomputingindia/vedic-mathematics-vinculum-numbers.

Comment: For those who might be puzzled, my understanding of Vedic vinculum numbers is that they are base-$10$ numbers that can use negative digits, which are represented either with a vinculum (overbar) or as boldface. Any integer can be written in base $10$ using digits between $-5$ and $5$, so it can be simpler to convert to a vinculum number before performing mental (or by-hand) arithmetic, since you only need the “times table” up to $5\times5$. For example, $27\times82$ equals $3\bar3\times1\bar22=3\bar300+\bar660+6\bar6=3\bar960+6\bar6=3\bar82\bar6=2214$.

Comment: @SteveKass thanks